# Tailwind css hover not changing text color in my website

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui

I'm new in the tailwind CSS world. I try to change my colour on hover in a tailwind CSS. I use `hover:text-red-800`.
I try with two ways. But the hover colour is not changed.

First ways

```
 <a href="#">
    <h1 class="mt-2 text-black sm:text-2xl xl:text-2xl hover:text-red-800">Why javascript is so famous right now? 5</h1>
 </a>
```

Second way

```
 <a class="hover:text-red-800" href="#">
     <h1 class="mt-2 text-black sm:text-2xl xl:text-2xl hover:text-red-800">Why javascript is so famous right now? 5</h1>
 </a>
```

In both ways, hover colour not be changed. Please tell me what I do.
My `tailwind.config.js` file.

```
 module.exports = {
  purge: ["./public/**/*.html"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
    colors: {}
  },
  variants: {},
  plugins: []
  };
```

My `postcss.config.js` file looks like

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    require("tailwindcss"),
    require("autoprefixer"),
    ...(process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? [require("cssnano")] : []),
  ],
};
```

Comment: You have `colors` property in the `theme` object which is an empty object which removes all default colors. Just remove this property if you have no plans to using it.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try using the `postcss.config.js` like this:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  }
}
```

and `tailwind.config.js` like this:

```
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

And also try to use the latest version of `tailwindcss`

Follow this [link](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation/using-postcss) for configuring `tailwindcss` properly!